# Mailboxer and Backbone Integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

The application i am working on already has the mailbox gem implemented with backbone , now i am to replicate the same for two new and seperate devise models . I have read the code but as it's without any documentation i have been moving at a snail's pace . What i needed was how i can go on to extend the already implemented thing for User for UserA and UserB . I have already nested the mailboxer resource for both the resource , but how do i make sure the code i am writing for is for those particular models ? Any suggestions on this would be much appreciated , also a newbie to backbone which isn't helping much .

Comment: Could you provide a source code for the concrete case?

Comment: Yes , sure . Which part would you like to see ?

Comment: Where we can see what you want to extend - client side Backbone or Ruby?

Comment: The code is written for User Mailbox , for example the three option that mailbox provides - Inbox , Sent and trash , these 3 are provided on the same page using backbone . I want to implement the same on the new devise users i made .